# jQuery daterangepicker: executes alert twice?

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I want it to alert "ok" when you change/make a date. But i get two alerts instead of one?

How can i fix this?

here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#datePicking').daterangepicker({
           arrows:true,
           onChange: function(){                  
               alert('ok');
           }
       }); 
});
```

I am using jquery 1.3.2 and UI 1.7.2

Comment: please fix your cod as it is a bit hard to read. $('#Viewer') alert('ok'); <-- what does that mean? why just a call to $("#viewer")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is known issue with the plugin.

From Scott (Filament) at [filamentgroup](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework):

> I added a callback function for
>   onChange now that you might be able
>   use. Keep in mind that it may not fit
>   your needs exactly because it will
>   fire on EVERY change that occurs in
>   the input. One-click range shortcuts
>   will actually fire 2 change callbacks
>   because this plugin simply triggers
>   date changes on each datepicker, one
>   at a time. Once this plugin is adopted
>   by jQuery UI, I’m sure we’ll work that
>   part out and have the rangepicker
>   firing events as one widget. For now,
>   you’ll need to set up your page with
>   this issue in mind.

A workaround for this might be to use `$('#datePicking').blur()` instead of the `onChange` option of the plugin.

Comment: Actually, when u click the "last 7 days" and "Yesterday" options also it triggering twice(i.e, using ajax call to retrieve results for that selected date from database. So, the ajax call triggering twice )

Comment: can u just explain where i can place the blur()

Comment: @user655334: You can just chain it after daterangepicker: `$('#datePicking').daterangepicker({..}).blur(function(){..});`

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use onClose instead of onChange

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datePicking').daterangepicker({
       arrows:true,
       onClose : function(){                  
           alert('ok');
       }
   }); 
});
```

try this it may help

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using daterangepicker with angular. My purpose is to watch any change in the model that stores the date range value and save it for an AJAX call later. I face the same issue as it hits the event twice whenever the date is change even if it is only 'Today': ***Once it is object with startDate and endDate properties, and the other time it is a string.***

It can be made use of as an advantage.

```
 $scope.$watch(
    'rangeOfDate',
    function (newValue) {
        // Due to a known bug of open source library daterangepicker, the event is hit twice 
        //upon change. Once it is an object, and once it is a string. So, use appropriately.
        var selectedDateRange = new Object();
        if (typeof (newValue) == 'object') {
            selectedDateRange.startDate = new Date(newValue.startDate).toLocaleDateString();
            selectedDateRange.endDate = new Date(newValue.endDate).toLocaleDateString();
            //Do as you wish with this custom object
        }
        else if (typeof (newValue) == 'string') {
            alert("string");
        }               
    },
    false);
```